# Remotely controlling Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows, remote-control

I am looking for a way to control my Windows 8 machine from my Android device.

I have seen there are some server/clients around, but I'm not sure if they fit my needs. To be clear: I am not looking to session into my RDP, I want to remote control some of my Windows  8 apps.

Comment: What kind of applications? Audio/video could be done by pairing with bluetooth if they support the remote control profiles.

Comment: Why not run a VNC server on your Windows 8 machine, then use a VNC client (available on any platform)...?

Answer (score 2):

Unified remote has worked very well for me in the past.

[Website](http://www.unifiedremote.com)

[Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  [TeamViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile)? You can use it to control all OS.

Comment: thnx. I will look into it!